# Why would Ferris even be in economics?

Tags: plot-explanation, ferris-buellers-day-off

There's a famous scene from *[Ferris Bueller's Day Off](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091042/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt)* where Ferris's economics teacher (played by Ben Stein) takes roll, and Ferris is absent.

Well, later in the film there's another scene where Ferris uses his home computer to access the school's system, to change his number of absences from nine to two.

[image]

When looking at his computer screen, it shows his basic student information, and his current course schedule:

- ENG COMP (English Composition)
- CALCULUS
- CHEMISTRY
- LUNCH
- GYM
- COMPUTER SC (Computer Science)
- UTPIAN SCY (Utopian Society)
- EURO HIST (European History)

### But, what about economics?

The course Ben Stein is teaching definitely seems to be economics, since some of the topics include: the Great Depression, the Hawley-Smoot Tariff Act, and the Laffer curve.

Was this an oversight by the creators, or, is it mentioned at some point that Ferris perhaps switched courses mid semester? But, wouldn't that still be reflected in his course schedule?

Comment: There's a "PAGE 1" at the bottom of the screen - and not all days/periods are covered on the current page

Comment: @HorusKol So, you're suggesting that Ferris is taking more than 7 courses in a single semester, and, that his school day is longer than 8 hours (where 1 period = 15min)? Hmm...

Comment: The day that Ferris skips is on a Wednesday, because when they're at the ball game, Ferris mentions to Cameron that they'd be in gym class at that time. When looking at his course schedule for Wednesday, there's a class for each period interval. So, just going off that schedule, Ferris's entire Wednesday is accounted for.

Comment: Also, the baseball game itself was real, and was played on June 5th, 1985, which is a Wednesday.

Comment: I don't about US high schools - but I had 12 subjects on the go at the same age in the the UK... But with the additional information about the day, I retract my first comment.

Comment: From my experience, a typical US high school student carries 6-8 courses, sometimes less if they're doing co-op, and variation occurs most in how long the courses are. For 8 course high schools, there's "A day / B day", where each course is ~1h45m and each day contains 4 courses (hence A/B days). For 6-7 course high schools, each course is ~45m to 1h15m and all courses are within one day. The latter seems to be what Ferris's school does.

Comment: I lean towards it being simply overlooked, but just to play devil's court appointed public defender for a moment: couldn't "the Great Depression, the Hawley-Smoot Tariff Act, and the Laffer curve" all be reasonable things to discuss in a course on Utopian Society?  Economics would clearly play a large role in the creation or downfall of Utopias.

Comment: I notice in the screenshot that there is a column for the teacher's name; is Stein's character's name ever mentioned?

Comment: @LazyGadfly No, I don't believe so. On IMDb it's just "economics teacher". And, as for it being Utopian Society.. I really don't think the Great Depression would be considered a quality of a utopian society. To me, it just sounded like economic history of the US (Ben Stein also mentions George Bush, and how Bush refers to sth as "voodoo economics").

Answer (score 2):

Since European history is one of the subjects, maybe the course was European history.

The Great Depression was part of European History, causing, among other effects, the rise of the Nazis to power in Germany.

the Hawley-Smoot Tariff Act was part of European History, reducing trade between the USA and other countries including European ones, and thus making the Great Depression more depressing.

The Laffer Curve is an economic theory that applies, if valid, to European countries as well.

The list of teachers on the screen is:

ENG COMP     HOLLNDR

CALCULUS     MCMURRY

CHEMISTRY    GUNNER

LUNCH        *******

GYM          CARLYLE

COMPUTER SCI COWEN

UTPIAN SCY   JARDIN

EURO HIST    RICE

There are no characters listed with the Surnames of Hollander, McMurry, Gunner, Carlyle, Cowen, Jardin, or Rice.

There are three characters listed as teachers:

Edward Le Beau - Gym Teacher (could be Carlyle)

Del Close - English Teacher (could be Hollander)

Ben Stein - Economics Teacher (and maybe he is Rice teaching European History)

This may be a case of the right hand not knowing what the left hand is doing.  There may have been a change in the courses Ferris was supposed to have during production, and someone may not have got the memo.  Thus Ben Stein's character may have been listed as "Economics Teacher" in the credits and "European history teacher Rice" in Ferris' student file.

Since the room numbers seem to be clearly visible in the computer screen, checking to see if any are visible in any scene may be a good idea.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzDvH.jpg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzDvH.jpg)

Each of Ferris's courses is four days a week, which implies that every period occupied by a class should be open one day a week except Wednesday & Friday, which perhaps is a study hall at different periods each day.  Since all of the classes are on Wednesday there is no room for another one on Wednesday, the day Ferris skips school.

In any case, it seems to me that European History is the course where it would be the least odd or unlikely to discuss economic subjects, especially since 2 out of 3 are historical events.

Comment: *"Since European history is one of the subjects, maybe the course was European history".* -- I appreciate your efforts, but it can't be European history because Ben Stein's class was one of the first classes of the day; whereas, if you look at Ferris's schedule, European history is his *last* class of the day (during periods 30-32). So, just going off Ferris's schedule, it would have to be either Eng Comp, Calculus, or Chemistry, and it's clearly none of those.

Comment: Then I think it must be a case of Ferris having a different list of classes according to different  persons with different jobs who worked on the production.  An Inconsistency

Comment: I'd say you're right on though about why he skips on Wednesday(s).. if you look at his scores, his worst grades are in gym (a C and D). And then, when they're at the ballgame, Ferris makes a comment about how they'd otherwise be in gym class. So, perhaps a large majority of Ferris's *nine* absences were from him skipping Wednesdays to avoid gym, and because he doesn't have study hall on those days either.